# Can crocodilians differentiate their offsprings from other young crocodiles?

Tags: zoology, reproduction, ethology, perception

I read that some species of crocodilians can take care of their young for as long as a year.

How do parents differentiate their offsprings from other young crocodiles? Smell, appearance, sound?

Comment: Crocodiles have very keen hearing and can hear their babies calling from inside their egg. I believe mother crocodiles recognize the sound of babies after they hatch also.